# It's simple TypeError but :(

Tags: python, class, iterator

Hello I'm new in Python.

I'm trying to make a random iterator. But I receive TypeError which I couldn't figure out why :(
I normally see when it has such error ease but this one I didn't get my mistake.
Thank yoou in advance

INPUT

```
import random


class RandomInts:
    def __init__(self, length, *, seed=0, lower=0, upper=10):
        self.length = length
        self.seed = seed
        self.lower = lower
        self.upper = upper

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.RandomIterator(self.length,
                                   seed=self.seed,
                                   lower=self.lower,
                                   upper=self.upper)

    class RandomIterator:
        def __iter__(self, length, *, seed, lower, upper):
            self.length = length
            self.lower = lower
            self.upper = upper
            self.num_requested = 0
            random.seed(seed)

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self.num_requested >= self.length:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                result = random.randint(self.lower, self.upper)
                self.num_requested += 1
                return result

randoms = RandomInts(10)

for num in randoms:
    print(num)
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python_Learning\Avanced\5_sorting_iterables\sorting_iterables_1.py", line 42, in <module>
    for num in randoms:
  File "E:\Python_Learning\Avanced\5_sorting_iterables\sorting_iterables_1.py", line 15, in __iter__
    return self.RandomIterator(self.length,
TypeError: RandomIterator() takes no arguments
```

Comment: Why do you have two `__iter__` in `RandomIterator` ? The second one will overwrite the first one

Comment: AH! :) Blame the auto-correction. Should be init indeed. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean
`def __iter__(self, length, *, seed, lower, upper):`
or
`def __init__(self, length, *, seed, lower, upper):` in `RandomIterator`?

Comment: AH! :) Blame the auto-correction. Should be __init__ indeed.  THANK YOU!